# bitmap size exceeds VM budget for specific activity

Tags: android, performance

I have activity A, B and C. They all setContentView in which the XML uses a drawable a a background. I put my background drawable image in drawable-nodpi folder.

However, every once in a while, I get the following exception in crash report in activity B specifically

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:563)
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:439)
    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:697)
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1981)
    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:653)
    at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:1961)
    at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:1909)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:286)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:120)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:415)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:505)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:568)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:386)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:215)
    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1663)
    at com.mypackage.myapp.ActivityB.onCreate
```

The background drawable for that specifically is 67 KB and it is 1122 by 1682 pixels.

What should I do? I can't even reproduce it on my phone

Comment: Try sampling to get out from out of memory. U can use sampling on that background which is in B activity.

Comment: So you suggest that I don't load background from xml but load it from code(and do sampling)?

Comment: See this http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Comment: I tried looking it up and sampling basically reduce the height and width. The problem though is that the it is a background of the app so really the number of pixels is not that different. So i am not sure that sampling would be good

Comment: Sampling not reduce the height and width. You can pass your desired height and width. Just change the sampling size.

Comment: Yes but the sampling number is determined based on the original dimensions and the new dimensions you want to achieve. If you keep the same dimensions then sampling will be 1

Comment: you can do sampling with 2 and stretch it by giving its height and width. Yes it may be pixlated

Comment: Ah ok.  That makes sense. If you give it as an answer (including how to do stretching) then I will accept it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method Will do the sampling . You can modify sampling rate i.e. inSampleSize in my code.

```
public static int calculateInSampleSize(
BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
// Raw height and width of image
final int height = options.outHeight;
final int width = options.outWidth;
int inSampleSize = 2;

if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

// Calculate ratios of height and width to requested height and width
final int heightRatio = Math.round((float) height / (float) reqHeight);
final int widthRatio = Math.round((float) width / (float) reqWidth);

// Choose the smallest ratio as inSampleSize value, this will guarantee
// a final image with both dimensions larger than or equal to the
// requested height and width.
inSampleSize = heightRatio < widthRatio ? heightRatio : widthRatio;
}

return inSampleSize;
}

public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Resources res, int resId,
int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

// First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);

// Calculate inSampleSize
options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

// Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);
}
```

And at the last set this sampled Image in your Imageview or any another view. Using this

```
mImageView.setImageBitmap(decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(),R.id.myimage,    
Screen_width, screen_height));
```