# Android Heap memory issue on loading application

Tags: android, memory

> I am having 5 bitmap images and my emulator heap memory is 32MB,while
>   i am debugging the code ,before entering bitmap decoding statement, on
>   app loading itself it is taking 29.02 MB , so that i cant load my
>   images,, please help me,, why application is growing heap memory on
>   loading... i should reduce this,so only i can able to access my
>   images.

```
    02-16 14:41:49.557: I/dalvikvm-heap(2212): Grow heap (frag case) to 10.719MB for 8640016-byte allocation

02-16 14:41:49.639: D/dalvikvm(2212): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 2% free 10862K/11060K, paused 81ms, total 81ms

02-16 14:41:49.709: D/dalvikvm(2212): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 2% free 10862K/11060K, paused 4ms+6ms, total 70ms

02-16 14:41:50.020: D/dalvikvm(2212): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 2% free 10862K/11060K, paused 25ms, total 25ms

02-16 14:41:50.400: I/dalvikvm-heap(2212): Grow heap (frag case) to 29.258MB for 19440016-byte allocation
```

Answer (score 1):

In the Android app, you have to take less size bitmap in your application. You can reduce the size either through the `PhotoShop`.

Comment: I have resized images,, but before going to decode,on loading itself,, app taking heap memory 29 MB, i.e while passing super() method in constructor...

Comment: Can you paste the total bitmap size of all the bitmaps?

Answer (score 0):

You can compress your **Bitmaps** by their **sampling size.** For more about how to do sampling if want to know checky my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18685835/bitmap-size-exceeds-vm-budget-for-specific-activity/18725731#18725731).

Comment: question is not that,, if i use one image also,, while loading application,app taking heap memory 29 MB, i.e while passing super() method in constructor

Comment: Try to recycle your bitmaps.

Comment: @rahulkapoor If in a function there is a return bitmap drawable then , how would you actually recycling the bitmap after returning within the function.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reduce your bitmap image as possible.
You can use

```
 Bitmap newImage = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(photo, width, height, true);
```

Comment: question is not that,, if i use one image also,, while loading application,app taking heap memory 29 MB, i.e while passing super() method in constructor

Comment: I got u. You need to check why your app taking those memory in loading. What is  the data which is loaded with start up?
Can you share your activity and layout?

Comment: @TechBee Did you find suitable solution for your problem?

Comment: @MinaTadros I'm too facing similar problems, at the start up of my app it takes 5seconds to start, when I see the log messages, its the map allocating memory for maptiles. Could you help me out please? Also see this thread:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23676419/osmdroid-mapview-reads-sdcard-state-if-mounted-before-load-of-mapview

Comment: @zIronManBox I did not used OSM before but you need to know if this long time due to trying "loading tiles online" or due to the mount.
You are making your testing using real device or emulator? if not real device, try this on real device because the performance may be change based on the device type and SD Card.

Comment: @MinaTadros I'm using on real device - Nexus 7, I've alloted largeHeap and loading offline maps from mounted SDcard, yet i'm getting GC_FOR_ALLOC and UI goes unresponsive, can you help me in solving this memory allocation.

Comment: @zIronManBox As I told you, I did not work with OSM before. I just can give you some notes. 
You are assuming your problem related to memory allocation but this may be not the case here. Your main issue is the long time for the response as I got from your comments. You need to check the OSM performance to check the online maps, mount and load offline maps. Check also your app memory before and after opening OSM to know what is the reserved amount for those maps. Google take between 20M to 50M to load google maps based on the mobile resolution. You need to check that.