# My Created Android App Forceclose

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, forceclose

So I have this XML Problem is when I open it it gives me forces close. When I remove some image view let say only 7 total images views in XML it works. Any idea why? I don't know why its not working when there are more images on my xml

App3.XML

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/JCBG"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Products"
            android:textColor="@color/JCLogo"
            android:textSize="30dp"/>

        <ViewFlipper
            android:id="@+id/fliping"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <!--  The child Views/Layout to flip -->

        <!--  Layout 1 for 1st Screen -->

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal|center"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                        android:scaleType="fitXY"
                        android:src="@drawable/gr" />

            </LinearLayout>

             <!--  Layout 2 for 2nd Screen -->

            <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                        android:scaleType="fitXY"
                        android:src="@drawable/calvitcdetails" />

            </LinearLayout>

             <!--  Layout 3 for 3rd Screen -->

            <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                        android:scaleType="fitXY"
                        android:src="@drawable/kapedetails"/>

            </LinearLayout>

              <!--  Layout 4 for 4th Screen -->

            <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                        android:scaleType="fitXY"
                        android:src="@drawable/glutafitdetails"/>

            </LinearLayout>

              <!--  Layout 5 for 5th Screen -->

            <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageView5"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                        android:scaleType="fitXY"
                        android:src="@drawable/pgtdetails"/>

            </LinearLayout>


              <!--  Layout 6 for 6th Screen -->

            <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageView6"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                        android:scaleType="fitXY"
                        android:src="@drawable/hilifedetails"/>

            </LinearLayout>


                <!--  Layout 7 for 7th Screen -->

            <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageView7"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                        android:scaleType="fitXY"
                        android:src="@drawable/organicbarleyjuicedetails"/>

            </LinearLayout>

                <!--  Layout 8 for 8th Screen -->

            <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageView8"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                        android:scaleType="fitXY"
                        android:src="@drawable/barleydetails"/>

            </LinearLayout>

             <!--  Layout 9 for 9th Screen -->

            <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageView9"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                        android:scaleType="fitXY"
                        android:src="@drawable/spirulinadetails"/>

            </LinearLayout>

              <!--  Layout 10 for 10th Screen -->

            <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageView10"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                        android:scaleType="fitXY"
                        android:src="@drawable/omnisoapdetails"/>

            </LinearLayout>


             <!--  Layout 11 for 11th Screen -->

            <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageView11"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                        android:scaleType="fitXY"
                        android:src="@drawable/omnipinkishdetails"/>

            </LinearLayout>


            <!--  Layout 12 for 12th Screen -->

            <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageView12"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                        android:scaleType="fitXY"
                        android:src="@drawable/omnidaydetails"/>

            </LinearLayout>


            <!--  Layout 13 for 13th Screen -->

            <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageView13"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                        android:scaleType="fitXY"
                        android:src="@drawable/omnitonerdetails"/>

            </LinearLayout>


        </ViewFlipper>

</LinearLayout>
```

Activity3.java

```
    package com.example.jcw;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.ViewFlipper;

public class activity3 extends Activity 
{

    private ViewFlipper vf;
    private float lastX;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.app3);
    vf = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.fliping);
    }



    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent touchevent) {
    switch (touchevent.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
    lastX = touchevent.getX();
    break;
    }
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
    float currentX = touchevent.getX();
    if (lastX < currentX) {
        if (vf.getDisplayedChild() == 0)
            break;
            vf.setInAnimation(this, R.anim.in_from_left);
            vf.setOutAnimation(this, R.anim.out_to_right);
            vf.showNext();
    }
    if (lastX > currentX) {
        if (vf.getDisplayedChild() == 1)
            break;
            vf.setInAnimation(this, R.anim.in_from_right);
            vf.setOutAnimation(this, R.anim.out_to_left);
            vf.showPrevious();
            }
            break;
            }
        }   
        return false;
}




}
```

Comment: plz post your logcat

Comment: My LOGCAT http://notepad.cc/share/pPSPyDmYdZ

Comment: For handling Out of memory. Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18685835/bitmap-size-exceeds-vm-budget-for-specific-activity/18725731#18725731

Answer (score 1):

`ImageView` widgets use `Bitmaps` which consume a lot of heap space. Therefore if you try to load to many images at the same time you will get `OutOfMemoryError` which is probably in your Logcat.

In case bitmaps resolutions are higher than really needed for display, you can optimize loading them, [here](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html) you will find Google's example how to do it.

If it's not the case then you have to design your app different way.

Comment: Thanks! But sorry I'm new at android development and java. I understand I need to resize, but how can i use the provided codes and call the images i have and automatically resize it.

Comment: Do not set `android:src` for `ImageView`. Instead use `findViewById()` in your `Activity` to get ImageView references. Then in the background thread, for example using `AsyncTask`, load resized bitmaps and set them  as sources of your `ImageView` references. Loading bitmaps and setting on UI views example can be found under linked documentation in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Add this in thatthe appmanifest:
android:largeHeap="true"

Answer (score 0):

you can change your   `<ViewFlipper ... </ViewFlipper>`  to this   `<AdapterViewFlipper />`
for this you need chaange your layout to this one:

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@color/JCBG"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Products"
        android:textColor="@color/JCLogo"
        android:textSize="30dp"/>

    <AdapterViewFlipper 
        android:id="@+id/flipper"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

then you need to create new layout and put below code to that:

mLayout.xml

```
<LinearLayout
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         android:gravity="center"
         android:orientation="vertical">

         <ImageView
             android:id="@+id/imageView"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
             android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

in your main activity after getting adapterViewFlipper view set adapter for it:

```
adapterViewFlipper.setAdapter(new BAdapter(this,yourImageResourceArray));
```

after this you should create custom adapter (for example extend base adapter) and in it's get view method,inflate mLayout.xml and findView of ImageView and then set your Image for it.

this is sample of customAdapter that you need:

```
 public class Badapter extends BaseAdapter{

Context context;
ArrayList<Integer> imageResources;

public Badapter(Context context,ArrayList<Integer> imageResources) {
    this.context = context;
    this.imageResources = imageResources;
}


@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return imageResources.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return imageResources.get(arg0);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View rowView = inflater
            .inflate(R.layout.mLayout, null, true);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    imageView.setBackgroundResource(imageResources.get(position));
    //if you use view Holder you will save more memory
    return rowView;
}

}
```

if you do this ,view will recycle and using less memory.
NOTE: if you use image with more than 50Kb size ,in **some** device your app will crash.so you should use image with lower size.